# Can we call other TestRunner file in the karate feature file

Tags: karate

trying to call other test runner class (basically its is TestNG file) in the karate feature file. 
Feature:

```
  Background:
    * def processRequest = Java.type('com.walmart.testrunnerclass.processRequest')

    Scenario:
      Given processRequest.feature
```

is this the right way of calling. also is there any keywords that needs to be used?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean using a Java class, you can, see the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

```
* def JavaDemo = Java.type('com.mycompany.JavaDemo')
* def result = JavaDemo.doWorkStatic('world')
```

Comment: this Java class can be with TestNG tags being used.  so basically i am trying to call a TestNG java file in the feature file.

Comment: @SumanthMylar sounds like you are doing something un-necessary, maybe someone else can help you - I am giving up

Comment: i am trying to build one unified framework for our team by integrating the existing framework with karate . this integration is necessary as we are moving from legacy to new age and the tests needs to start in legacy

Comment: @SumanthMylar whatever that is - there is no need to call TestNG from Karate in my opinion. Karate doesn't depend on JUnit also if you use the parallel runner. I think you are going down the wrong path. all the best

Comment: thanks Peter, redirecting me . i guess the approach i should take is calling Java classes in the feature file. trying that out. will come back with results